# I/O interface for portable library

Tags: c#, .net, io

I'm writing a new .NET portable library that can read a file format, and file I/O is not available for portable libraries. The article "[How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsplaisted/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you)" states that I'll have to write platform-specific libraries to solve this for each platform. That's not a problem.

So, I'll have the file format reading code in the portable library, and then some platform-specific libraries to help with platform-specific I/O: one platform-specific library will be written using traditional traditional .NET `System.IO.File`, whereas the Windows Store apps-library will use `Windows.Storage` and the Windows Phone one will use `System.IO.IsolatedStorage`. I know WinRT is all asynchronous, but I only have experience with the traditional .NET `File` and synchronous I/O.

Each of these platform-specific libraries will reference the portable library and provide the file format reader with a platform-specific implementation of a data source object:

```
ISomeDataSource dataSource = new WinRTDataSource(@"filename.bin");
var reader = new FileFormatReader(dataSource);
```

**How do I design the interface (e.g. the `ISomeDataSource` above) such that I can read and seek within the data?** But then platform-agnostic and maybe even asynchronous?

I have access to all features of Visual Studio 2012 and C# 5 (`async` and `await`), but since I'm not on Windows 8 I cannot try WinRT.

Comment: Is `IDataSource` [Microsoft's interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.idatasource.aspx), or is it a custom one you are writing?  If it's yours, simply define `Read()` and `Seek()` methods on the interface, and then code the necessary implementations in each platform-specific wrapper.

Comment: Do you even need to design a new interface? Won't `Stream` work for you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No I meant my own. Changed it now in my post.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your problem.  Why isn't it as simple as defining the interface I described in my comment above, and writing three implementations that inherit that interface?

Comment: @svick Well, maybe `Stream` _is_ enough for me... if it is possible to get a `Stream` out of WinRT and Windows Phone. If so, you should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything hard about this, you can just create the interface (using asynchronous method for `Read()`) and then implement it three times:

```
interface ISomeDataSource
{
    Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
    long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin);
}
```

Both signatures are copied from `Stream`. Which is another option: use `Stream` instead of your interface. It has `ReadAsync()`, `Seek()` and more.

You can do this since `System.IO` and `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` directly use `Stream` ([`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) in `System.IO` and [`IsolatedStorageFileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx) in `System.IO.IsolatedStorage`). WinRT has its own stream types, but you can convert those to `Stream` using extension methods from [`WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions.aspx).